# Session Check bypassed vulnerability

Tags: php, security, get

We have a php page which is the admin section of the website. It is used to perform some update actions on the database. The code looks like follows

```
session_start(); 
     if (!isset($_SESSION['somevariable']) ) 
        {
        header("Location:loginpage.php");
        }



    $id=$_GET['somevariable];
$sql = "UPDATE sometable SET somecolumn='' where someothercolumn=?";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s',$id);
$stmt->execute();
```

What we have noticed is there has been some vulnerability and this piece of code seems to be running from an unknown source at a periodic interval(5 seconds), which doesnt seem like someone has the password for the admin section and is running the actions manually.

We would like to know can a hacker bypass this login check and execute the rest of the code without having the password? Any insights into the vulnerability in the above piece of code will be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: noticed a quote missing in code!

Comment: @knittl Any advice on how the attacker could have done that and how could it be avoided? Will changing it to a POST instead of a get help?

Comment: @MaximDsouza: [pouya darabi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25990765/112968) is correct. `header` will not stop script execution

Comment: @MaximDsouza use `session.use_strict_mode=On`. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/session.security.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw two vulnerabilities:

1) CSRF (using variable directly from get method )

2) Exit not used after calling header function

Correct code should be like this:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

See php.net document 
[Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: Is it possible for the code below to execute even though the redirect is before the other set of code? I mean the scenario where the exit is not present?

Comment: if you don't use exit after header function
your code continue to executing

Comment: if you want sure browser get redirect you must use exit after redirect code !

Comment: +1 … almost overlooked the missing `exit` call. `header` will only send an http header but keep executing the script

Comment: Thanks a lot people. We will keep this in mind. Any other inputs will also be taken as learning.

Answer (score 0):

If an admin has an active session, and a hacker somehow finds out the value of their `PHPSESSID` cookie, they can send the cookie and hijack the session.

Make sure you use SSL encryption, to make it difficult for someone to eavesdrop on the connection and get the cookies.

Comment: We are pretty sure that when the attack happened the admin was not logged in.

Comment: Then the attacker must be logging in somehow. Sessions only get created when PHP scripts create them.